# What is the meaning of this sentence "as their jump ropes slap hot concrete"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She is the one the girls sing about as their jump ropes slap hot concrete.

Can anybody explain the meaning of "as their jump ropes slap hot concrete"?

Comment: I suspect that the answer will be obvious to you after you look at this site. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipping_rope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stealing Jeff's comment and making it an answer

> A **skipping rope** (British English) or **jump rope** (American English) is a
>   tool used in the sport of skipping/ jump rope where one or more participants
>   jump over a rope swung so that it passes under their feet and over
>   their heads.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skipping_rope

It needs no further explanation now.